# Lohse is not on-board the Lady Vengence

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I've just defeated Alexander and am aboard the Lady Vengence.

I can find all 5 characters aboard except Lohse.

I've searched all 3 decks to no avail. She is simply not on the ship.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: Is Lohse in your party ?

Comment: ^ or is she dead

Answer (score 1):

I quit the game, started it again and reloaded my save and she's there now. Must've been a bug.